# Apply CSS to a generated href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am generating links from a java script to created a breadcrumb for my sight. It works perfectly, but.... I want to put all the link in a line like this,

```
.a
{
   display: inline;
   float : left;
   font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
}
```

but I don't know where to put the css to make it pretty. 
Here is the javascript that is inside the body of the html;

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
var path = "";
var href = document.location.href;
var s = href.split("/");
for (var i=2;i<(s.length-1);i++) {
    path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+"</A> \>\> ";
}
i=s.length-1;
path+="<A HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf(s[i])+s[i].length)+"\">"+s[i]+"</A>";
var url =  path;
document.write(url);
//-->
</script>
```

Right now the links are one on top of each other with the >> at the left side of the page. 
I want them to be inline horizontally with the >> in-between them.

Comment: `.a` selects elements which include a class `a` ...  `a` selects `<a>` tags

Comment: yes I know but I want to change just this particular links not any of the other links that I already have css applied to.

Comment: `I don't know where to put the css to make it pretty` traditionally, in page style goes in a `<style>` tag ... external style goes in a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="..." />` ... on that note, `<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">` is very 1990's ... `<script type="text/javascript">` is better, but in HTML5 just `<script>` is quite fine ... and I wont mention everything that's wrong with `document.write`

Comment: Oh, well, give those breadcrumb links a class, like "breadcrumb" ... then change the CSS to be `a.breadcrumb` ... then only `<a class="breadcrumb ...">` links will be styled how you want

Comment: Good point on the document.write, I will look into other methods for writing the links thank you very much

Comment: If you are floating, you don'tneed to specify display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css should be:

```
a
{
   display: inline-block;
   font: 18px Helvetica, Arial, Sans-Serif; 
}
```

1. You are calling `.a class` instead of `a`
2. You don't need to use `float: left` for this case

Comment: That is just for an example of what I want to do with the link. I don't know how to add a class or a id to the generated links

Comment: Your can simple use jQuery to add class:
`$("a").each(function(){
 $(this).addClass("YourCLass");
})`

Comment: will this add the class to other a on the page or just the ones in the javascript?

Comment: Did you try to add class inside the string?
`path+="<A class='YourClass' HREF=\""+href.substring(0,href.indexOf("/"+s[i])+s[i].length+1)+"/\">"+s[i]+"</A> \>\> ";`

Comment: The jquery code will add `YourClass` to all `a` tag in the document.

Comment: I have added the class='tag' to the href and it work i used class = "tag" which didn't work. Its a little spotty, but I think that just something I have to work out by playing with it. Thanks